# Handling Extra Delimiters in CSV using Pandas read_csv

Tags: pandas, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV file that occasionally has delimiters within text fields. I don't have quote characters and don't have control over how I get this information.

I want to be able to add extra columns so that I can identify the incorrect lines easily and then work to fix them.

I'm currently using the following code and getting the following error:

```py
  for df in pd.read_csv(input_text_file, chunksize=20000, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8', sep='|',     quoting=3, na_values=''): 

    df.names = ['RealColumns1', 'RealColumns2', 'RealColumns3', 'ExtraColumn1', 'ExtraColumn2', 'ExtraColumn3] 

    df.to_sql('Table', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Error:

> Expected 3 fields in line 23685498, saw 4

I was expecting since I added the extra columns it would simply add 4 columns when it arrived a line with an additional delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a few more different tries.

seems like once I defined my column names prior to my for loop and stating header = None it appeared to work. It looks like this:

So my code now looks like this:

```python
     names = ['RealColumns1', 'RealColumns2', 'RealColumns3', 'ExtraColumn1', 'ExtraColumn2', 'ExtraColumn3] 

 for df in pd.read_csv(input_text_file, chunksize=20000, header = None, dtype = names, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8', sep='|', quoting=3, na_values=''): 


    df.to_sql('Table', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```